# Passing vector with unknown size to function

Tags: c++, function, vector

I want to pass the vector to the function.
The vector may be like as follows:

```
vector<array<int, 1>>& b1
vector<array<int, 2>>& b1
vector<array<int, 3>>& b1
vector<array<int, 4>>& b1
```

I write the following statement into the head file

```
ExportIBigEndian(string file_i, vector<array<int, >>& b1)
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Why do you need a vector of arrays?

Comment: @tkausl The reason I explain is in the comment of the answer from Brucher

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a vector of all types of arrays to a "simple" function, you must make it template as well:

```
template<int size>
ExportIBigEndian(string file_i, vector<array<int, size>>& b1)
```

Then the question is why not a vector of vector in that case?

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason is some part of the program is written by my senior colleagues. They use the vector of arrays. Is there any difference? or Using the vector of arrays has some disadvantage?

Comment: It has the advantage of not being dynamic allocation when used directly, here, not sur about the real advantage, and has the disadvantage of having every size bing a different type.